# Why the below command prints nothing

Tags: python, printing

Why does the following python code not print anything?

```
def modulo (spam):
   if spam == 3 % 2: 
      print(spam)
```

Comment: what are you trying to archive with this code?

Comment: Who upvotes this kind of nonsense?

Comment: Hallo , I learn python with codecademy , and a question was that I should write a Python syntax

Comment: So , the Question .... Our final operator is modulo. Modulo returns the remainder from a division. So, if you type 3 % 2, it will return 1, because 2 goes into 3 evenly once, with 1 left over.   Instructions , Use modulo to set spam equal to 1. You can use any two numbers that will leave a remainder of 1 to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go back to the basics, because there are two parts to pay attention to that should be rudimentary to you by now. The first is the `==` operator:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> print(a==b)
False
>>> a = 2
>>> print(a==b)
True
```

The `==` operator corresponds with *boolean* values: True or False

The second is the `%` operator. The `%` operator divides the first number by the second number and returns the remainder. Take the following, for example:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> print(a%b) # 1/2 = 0 2's + 1 remainder
1
>>> print(b%a) # 2/1 = 2 1's + 0 remainder
0
```

Now onto your code:

```
def modulo(spam):
    if spam == 3 % 2: # if spam is one (3/2 = one 2, plus 1 remainder)
        print(spam)
    else: # I'd add this, so you know the method is being run
        print("Spam is not 1.")
```

Comment: sorry ... I think it is , else : print (" 2 % 3") ??

Comment: It depends on what you want. If you want to print the string "2 % 3" then that's what it will do. If you want to print the result of 2%3 (which is 2) you'll type `print(2%3)`

Comment: Hallo , can you Please  help me , I have to try to done what your tell me , without success . I learn Python since two Months with automatetheboringstuff.com , I am now in Chapter 4 . Can you Please all code to write . Thanks

Comment: If you have a separate question, then you should ask it in a new thread because this thread has been solved. However, before asking the question you will want to try searching StackOverflow to see if there is thread that already answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the python code is indented correctly, nothing probably printed because `3%2` is equal to `1` and `spam` must not be equal to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the condition `spam == 3 % 2` is not true so it won't enter into `print(spam)`. Try debugging it.